# How to set a link to custom archieve page

Tags: posts, categories, archives

I am working on my blog where I wish to have a archieve for only specific category post. To make it, I create a custom archive-cat.php. So for example I can get archive link date by wp_get_archives(). So I just want when I clicked on archive date the whole archive data should come from my specific category.

For it, I have looked into wp-includes/general-templates.php -> wp_get_archive() and wp_archive_link(). Honestly I could not found the way to understand in actually how the archieve date link open archive template...

In other word I want to change the link template for archieve date link

So guide me in the right direction to solve my issue what should I do..

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on my blog where I wish to have a archieve for only
>   specific category post.

If I understand you, you are doing this wrong. What you want to do is use `pre_get_posts` to restrict your archives to the one category. Something like this:

```
function restrict_archives_to_cat($qry) {
  if ($qry->is_main_query() && $qry->is_date()) {
    $qry->set('cat',5); // the category ID you wish to use
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','restrict_archives_to_cat');
```

I don't understand the question well enough to get the conditions right, with any confidence. You may have to [alter the `if` conditions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to make this work correctly.